# How to import language pack in vtigercrm71?

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

I had installed new vtigercrm71. I've new language pack as chi_ch.zip but don't know how to import it in CRM. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to simply install it from Module Manager. 
If you are new in Vtiger, Follow the steps to go to Module Manager.

Click on Gear Icon (Top Right Corner) > CRM Setting > Studio (Left Navigation) > Module Manager > Click Install From Zip Button > Select your language pack zip file and Install.

> Note : Make sure you have valid format of zip file otherwise it will not work.